# How to redirect angularjs to template by url path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show content based on the `url`. The path `localhost:8080/test1` should show content from a different template than `localhost:8080/test2` etc.

But the following does not work and I'm getting a `404`. Why?

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/test1", {
        templateUrl : "./templates/test1.html",
        controller : "test1Controller"
    }).when("/test2", {
        templateUrl : "./templates/test2.html",
        controller : "test2Controller"
    }).otherwise({
        templateUrl : "./templates/error.html"
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Folder structure:

```
static/js/main.js (file above)
static/js/test1Controller.js
static/js/test2Controller.js
static/templates/test1.html
static/templates/test2.html
static/index.html
```

Comment: why did you put `dot` before template name, `./templates/error.html`?

Comment: Because the main.js is inside `/js` folder, so I go one level up to `/static`, and then into `/templates`. Anyways removing the dot makes not difference and still getting a 404.

Comment: how about `/static/templates/test2.html` ?

Comment: `.` doesn't go up one level - you need `..`, no? Also, the URLs are relative to `index.html` (or whatever page your app has), not to `.js` files

Comment: Ok, but then `/templates/...` should work, but it does not.

Comment: Use absolute path. is there any folder before `static`? try to do this: `/path/to/static/tempaltes/test2.html`

Comment: Don't use the forward `/` - just `templateUrl: "templates/test1.html"`

Comment: sounds like server isn't configured to allow using `html5Mode`. Is there a base tag? What 404 are you actually getting .... the url entered in address bar or the template ajax request?

Comment: What do you mean by "base tag"?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm getting a `HTTP status 400 - the requested resource is not available`

Comment: that doesn't answer the question of main page 404 or template 404 ... there's a difference. Read $location docs regarding `<base>` tag as well as MDN docs

Comment: I'm accessing `localhost:8080/test1` and the 404 is about `/test1`, so I guess this is the main page error. But when I go directly to `localhost:8080/test1/index.html` the html page is displayed. Just the url path mapping with angularjs is not working. Also I can access `localhost:8080/templates/test1.html` directly, which of course results in a weired html page as the template is to be embedded into another html file with angularjs. But this shows the resources can be found by the webserver in general.

Comment: Concerning base-tag: `<base href="/">` as all my resources are to be found directly without a basetag behind 8080.

Comment: Interestingly I found out: when using the url `localhost:8080/#test1`, this would rewrite the url to `localhost:8080/test1` and launch the correct webpage! **Question**: why, and how can I achieve that also the normal `/test1` link wil directly work? (as the users may bookmark this specific page).